# How to set default checked value for radio using ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

`public bool MyBool { get; set; }`

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label"></label>
   <div class="form-check my-2">
        <input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="true" checked />
        <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check my-2">
        <input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="false" />
        <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="MyBool" class="text-danger small"></span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set Yes (true) as checked. However, No is always checked instead.
I think it may be the tag helper but not sure how to change it so that it renders the way I want to.

Using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: For Create operation , you code has no problem and the Yes item will be checked .But for other operation like Edit , the checked item is up to the MyBool value of the passed model .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the tag helper that's causing the issue which in hindsight does make sense. I believe because the bool property does not have a value, it's defaulting to false and overwriting the fact that I'm setting checked on Yes.

The way I've resolved it is by removing checked altogether and instead initialising the booleans in the ViewModel constructor. That way the tag helper automatically selects the initial value.

Something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyBool = true;
    }
}



<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label"></label>
    <div class="form-check my-2">
        <input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="true" />
        <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check my-2">
        <input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="false" />
        <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="MyBool" class="text-danger small"></span>
</div>
```

I'd appreciate any further input if anyone has any.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user can just select one of radio button with default (checked), use code like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-check-label"></label>
<div class="form-check my-2">
  <input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" checked="checked" name="MyBool" type="radio" />
  <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check my-2">
  <input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" name="MyBool" type="radio" />
  <label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">No</label>
</div>
</div>
```

But it's better to use check box :

```html
<input asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<label asp-for="MyBool" class="form-check-label">Yes or No</label>
```